# Is it "regular sports training" or "regularly sports training"?

Tags: adjectives, british-english, adverbs

Should I say "regular sports training" or "regularly sports training"? Are we dealing with "sports training" as a one noun and then modify it by an adjective or  should it be modified by an adverb because *sports* is an adjective?

Comment: Typically you'll only add the `-ly` suffix, if the adverb is describing a verb. _They train regularly._

Comment: 'You need to supply a full sentence. 'Regular sports training improves overall fitness' is fine, as is 'Regularly training keeps you generally fit'.  But the _ING_-forms are different and 'regularly training' does not accept the modifier 'sports'. 'Sports-train' is not established as a compound verb.

Answer (score 1):

*regular sports training*

Even if *sports* was an adjective, the word *regular* modifies the whole phrase *sports training*, and *training* (which is the head of the phrase) is a noun. If you leave out *sports*, you have *regular training*, which is still valid.

Comment: So, why are we saying well paid jobs or well established author or so?

Comment: They are jobs that are _well paid_, so here _well_ modifies the adjective. But in the example, you don't have training that is 'regularly sports, but sometimes not'.